# How to get local url of asp.net core app at startup

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-5

I have an ASP.NET Core 5 app that I host in IIS.

When starting the app, I would like to hit some of my Web API's in order to initialize some services.

**Is possible to access Port and PathBase in Startup.cs?**

Then I could  build the request url like `https://localhost:{Port}/{PathBase}/api/startup/init`

Comment: Why do you need to actually call the API to initialise things? Just init during startup.

Comment: well, in mu case there is also a healthcheck as part of the startup.

Comment: But the health check is being done locally, so call it locally - why must you call out via the HTTP interface?

Comment: And I need the URL in general, not just startup because the app is calling itself in some scenarios (rendering html emails, comvertimg html to pdf) , so it would be cool if I could get the url without configuring it

Comment: Then you absolutely need to configure it. A web app can be listening on any URL/port but the external URL may be hidden behind a proxy or firewall. There is no way to get the URL programatically.

Comment: I don't need external url, local port and basepath (Virtual Directory in IIS) is just fine.

Comment: But if you're sending those out via an email for people to click on, you absolutely do need those details.

Comment: I'm not sending the URLs via emails. I have emails template implemented as razor pages and my app sends request to razor pages in order to download the html. I also use pupeteer to convert some razor pages to PDF, where pupeteer sends request to my app using localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer you "can't" retrieve if its supplied by lauchSettings.json. The best way to get around this and always have access to the url in the startup is by changing the `Program.cs`. Create a static class (or another solution) to store the url:

```
public static class Settings{ readonly string Url = "your_url"}
```

Then reference it from `Program.cs`

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                    webBuilder.UseUrls(Settings.Url);
                });
```

And then just retrieve from wherever you want using `Settings.Url`

Use the `UseUrls` configuration to supply the url from code instead from a lauchsettings.json file.

**Be extra carefull when deploying like that**

The url needs to have a single source of truth in your application and its not considered the best practice that way as its up to the server where the application will listen at. I would go with @DavidG suggestion to call it with code whatever service you want.